# Corner parcel frontages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, planning

We’re working on an evaluation of parcel conformity within zoning districts for a city and need to calculate frontage for all parcels. We’re able to do this for all parcels with the exception of corner parcels because of there being frontages for two streets. We’ve tried several approaches to connect the parcel address with the correct frontage (facing the address’ street) without result.

Does anyone have experience with addressing this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could add what approaches you have tried?